# Variables (possibly) get out of scope

Tags: java, inheritance, scope

Ok, so have two classes `Player` and child class `Classes`. I use the child class to set the player stats inside main class through switch statement that lets user choose his class. But for some reason the set variables fall out of scope when executed in main class. For the love of me, I can't figure why is it happening

Here is the `Player` class:

```
public class Player {
private int HP;
private int ATK;
private int DEF;
private int DAMAGE;

    void setHP(int a){
    HP=a;
    }

    void setATK(int a){
    ATK=a;
    }

    void setDEF(int a){
    DEF=a;
    }

    void setDAMAGE(){
    DAMAGE = damageCalculation();
    }

    int damageCalculation(){
    int damage = (2*ATK);    
    return damage;
    }

Player(String Class){
    Classes classes = new Classes();
switch(Class){
    case "Barbarian":
        classes.Barbar();
        System.out.println("Done");
        break;
        case "Rogue":
        break;
    default: System.out.println("Error");
}
}

void getStats(){
System.out.format("Player stats:"
        + "\nHP: %d"
        + "\nATK: %d"
        + "\nDEF: %d"
        + "\nDAMAGE: %d\n",HP,ATK,DEF,DAMAGE);
}
}
```

Here is the `Classes` class(note that in child class get stats return valid values):

```
public class Classes extends Player {

public void Barbar(){
Player player = new Player();   
player.setHP(60);
player.setATK(15);
player.setDEF(25);
player.setDAMAGE();
player.getStats();
 }
}
```

And here is the `main` class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SurvivalGame {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in,"Windows-1250");
    System.out.println("Enter your class");
    Player player = new Player(scan.nextLine());
    player.getStats(); //here getStats return zeros,
    //possibly out of scope variables if player enters Barbarian
 }
}
```

Comment: what do you expect public void Barbar() method to do? Where do you call it? I suppose you wanted it to be a constructor, but that's not how constructors look like.

Comment: because you are creating a new instance of player inside the `barbar` constructor, instead of using the parent `Player`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an extra instance of `Player` that is never accessed. Just walk through your code:

```
/* Main Method */
// You get a new Player object using direct user input
// (Which is somewhat dangerous, you should do some data validation first)
Player player = new Player(scan.nextLine())

/* Player constructor */
// Let's say user entered correctly "Barbarian". You are in the process of constructing
// a new Player object when you call this:
classes.Barbar();

/* Barbar method */
// The very first line creates a brand new player - different from one you were
// in the process of constructing. 
Player player = new Player(); 
// Then you assign values to the new Player, which goes out of scope as soon as the
// method ends.
```

Instead of having `Classes` extend `Player` (which seems a bit odd to me, to be honest), I'd just make the Barbar method belong to the Player class itself (which can then be called during your switch statement). Then you can just modify the current Player's values directly, instead of relying on a different class to do that for you.

For example:

```
public class Player 
{
    public Player(String class)
    {
        switch (class)
        {
            case "Barbarian": 
                Barbar();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Barbar()
    {
        HP = 60;
        ATK = 15;
        DEF = 25;
        setDAMAGE();
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured out it would be better to have all player classes in separate class to not have 10 page player class, but I guess your solution is somewhat more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Barbar(){
Player player = new Player();
```

If you look closely you are creating a new Player and adding values to that, not the Player in main method.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class, you get something that is an instance of the superclass, but with the extra methods and fields that you choose to add in the subclass. So when you write

```
public class Classes extends Player {
    //...
}
```

Your `Classes` instances already have the `HP` (etc.) fields in them. Your `Barbar` method can modify them without needing to create a new instance of `Player`:

```
public void Barbar(){
    setHP(60);
    setATK(15);
    setDEF(25);
    setDAMAGE();
    getStats();
}
```

You're confusing *composition* and *inheritance*.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still returns zeros in main class when invoked, but in the subclass it returns correct values.